# How to merge a time formatted cell with other cells as (hh:mm:ss) instead of it being displayed as a decimal number?

Tags: excel, date, merge

I was trying to merge a time format cell with other cells.
 The whole cell should look this way after merging:

```
Thu Feb 13 16:20:23 2014
```

But, what I get is this:

```
Thu Feb 13 0.680821759259259 2014
```

This is the formula that I have used for merging:
`=A1&" "&B1&" "&C1&" "&D1&" "&E1`
Is there a way I can merge in such a way that I can have the date to be printed in the format `hh:mm:ss` instead of the decimal number that I got?

Comment: Thanq very much.. it worked.. !!!

Answer (score 0):

Your result is text, so go ahead and turn your values into text before merging.  If you get the result you say, then D1 must hold the time.  Try: `=A1&" "&B1&" "&C1&" "&text(D1,"hh:mm:ss")&" "&E1` or `=A1&" "&B1&" "&C1&" "&text(D1,"h:mm:ss am/pm")&" "&E1`